# Using NSPredicate to search an array with an array

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate

I have an array of `Card` objects (NSObjects), each with a field called `tags`, which is an NSArray of NSStrings.

I would then like to split up the user's search term into an array called `keywords` of strings by `componentsSeparatedByString`, then use NSPredicate to filter my array of Cards based on which elements have tags containing at least 1 keyword in `keywords`.

I hope that's not too convoluted! I've tried using the NSPredicate `IN` clause to no avail. How should I do this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Considering `array` contains card Object.

```
 NSArray *keyWordsList = [keywords componentSeparatedByString:@","];
 [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K IN %@",@"tags",keyWordsList]]
```

EDIT:

To search partially you can use LIKE operator.

```
[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K LIKE[cd] %@",@"tags",[partialkeyWord stringByAppendingString:@"*"]]]
```

Comment: Oh man this is even simpler.. I've tried both answers, and they both function equally well!

Comment: how can I implement partial search in this? So if the user types "Bask" the `Card` with the tag "Basketball" shows up?

Comment: Right, but does this remove the functionality to search within the keywords array?

Answer (score 9):

Don't kill me if this isn't exactly right, but something like this will work.

```
NSArray* arrayOfCards = [NSArray array];
NSArray* keywords = [NSArray array];
NSPredicate* containsAKeyword = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    Card* card = (Card*)evaluatedObject;
    NSArray* tagArray = card.tags;
    for(NSString* tag in tagArray) {
       if( [keywords containsObject: tag] ) 
          return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}];

NSArray* result = [arrayOfCards filteredArrayUsingPredicate: containsAKeyword];
```

Comment: I'm in love with the answer by @Vignesh

Comment: I forgive you. I mean it is the first time I have seen ANY used correctly